# How to resolve "unexpected value 'stages' azure pipelines" in Azure devops pipeline yml

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-deployment, azure-pipelines-yaml

I am new to Azure devops. as part of poc, i am trying to build a java based docker image.

so i have following pipeline yaml file

```
# Maven
# Build your Java project and run tests with Apache Maven.
# Add steps that analyze code, save build artifacts, deploy, and more:
# https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/languages/java

trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

steps:
- task: Maven@3
  inputs:
    mavenPomFile: 'pom.xml'
    mavenOptions: '-Xmx3072m'
    javaHomeOption: 'JDKVersion'
    jdkVersionOption: '1.8'
    jdkArchitectureOption: 'x64'
    publishJUnitResults: true
    testResultsFiles: '**/surefire-reports/TEST-*.xml'
    goals: 'package'

resources:
- repo: self

variables:
  tag: '$(Build.BuildId)'

stages:
- stage: Build
  displayName: Build image
  jobs:  
  - job: Build
    displayName: Build
    pool:
      vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
    steps:
    - task: Docker@2
      displayName: Build an image
      inputs:
        command: build
        dockerfile: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/Dockerfile'
        tags: |
          $(tag)
```

## Expected

What i expected,  this pipeline need to create a java application (jar file) and then it should create a docker image using this jar

## Actual:

i am getting below error

```
unexpected value 'stages' azure pipelines
```

I didnt understand the issue...

Appreciated if anybody can help on this..?

Thanks

Comment: Please check if the answer below can resolve your issue. If yes, you could accept it as answer like [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please move this into job before your first task `- task: Docker@2`

```
steps:
- task: Maven@3
  inputs:
    mavenPomFile: 'pom.xml'
    mavenOptions: '-Xmx3072m'
    javaHomeOption: 'JDKVersion'
    jdkVersionOption: '1.8'
    jdkArchitectureOption: 'x64'
    publishJUnitResults: true
    testResultsFiles: '**/surefire-reports/TEST-*.xml'
    goals: 'package'
```

This is simply syntax issue. If you use steps you cant use stages on the root level. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema%2Cparameter-schema) you may check syntax.

If you want to have jar creation as separate stage/job you have to define explicitly this as another stage or job. However in that way you need to publish and then download your jar as [pipeline artifact](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/artifacts/pipeline-artifacts?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml).

If you stay with one single job you may just use:

```yaml
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

variables:
  tag: '$(Build.BuildId)'

steps:
- task: Maven@3
  inputs:
    mavenPomFile: 'pom.xml'
    mavenOptions: '-Xmx3072m'
    javaHomeOption: 'JDKVersion'
    jdkVersionOption: '1.8'
    jdkArchitectureOption: 'x64'
    publishJUnitResults: true
    testResultsFiles: '**/surefire-reports/TEST-*.xml'
    goals: 'package'
- task: Docker@2
  displayName: Build an image
  inputs:
    command: build
    dockerfile: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/Dockerfile'
    tags: |
      $(tag)
```

Comment: Thanks @Krzysztof Madej.. this helped to resolve it

Comment: @Adhi great! Can you consider voting up my answer if it was helpful for you?